# Remover campos criados em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi

Tenho a seguinte função para limpar os *edits* comuns:

```
for I := 0 to componentCount-1 do
  begin
  If(components [i] is Tedit) then
  Tedit(components[i]).Text := '';
  end;
```

porem possuo *edits* criados em tempo de execução, e gostaria que eles "desaparecessem" quando a pessoa clicar no botão de limpar.
Como posso incluir nessa minha função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se "desaparecessem" for não apresentá-los, basta fazer uma rotina parecida substituindo a linha

```
Tedit(components[i]).Text := '';
```

para

```
Tedit(components[i]).Visible := False;
```

Porém, se "desaparecessem" for destruir substitua por

```
Tedit(components[i]).Destroy;
```

Atenção. Ao usar o Destroy tenha em mente que o objeto foi destruído, então todas as futuras referências para estes objetos causarão uma violação de acesso. Devem-ser feitas proteções para este caso.

Comment: Gostaria que eles deixassem de existir, e depois quando alguém solicitar eles reaparecem, vou testar o destroy.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca use o Tedit(components[i]).Destroy diretamente no lugar Tedit(components[i]).Free que internamente faz o tratamento de liberação de memoria e chamada dos eventos corretos.!